# Biblatex, zero numbering when an unknown key is called with nocite and defernumbers

Tags: biblatex

In my "real" example, I need to print sorted bibliographies with a counter reset, so I need to use `defernumbers=true` and I need to use `\nocite{*}` coupled with real citations. I found that when a key is missing, the numbering is set to zero everywhere. Obviously for the final document, where all the keys are present, this is not a problem, but in the process of writing the document it is. Do you have a way to correct this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mabiblio.bib}
@misc{A-01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  location = {Location},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume = {1},
}
@article{C04,
  author = {Cuthor 2, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume = {2},
}
@article{B03,
  author = {Buthor 2, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mabiblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{authorA-01}% \cite{B02} \cite{C03}
\section{Biblio}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem if you replace the defective citation `\cite{authorA-01}` with the correct `\cite{A-01}`?

Comment: If I use only keys that are in the bibtex file, I do not have any problème. However, if I use a key that is not in the bibtex file, the numbering is set to 0 for all references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defernumbers` feature works by writing the label numbers to the `.aux` file. `biblatex` only does that once no further Biber calls are required, because the expectation is that a Biber call could potentially change the sorting, which would mean that the label numbers would change as well.

In the case of a missing/wrong entry key, you will always get a Biber rerun request, meaning that the label numbers are never written to the `.aux` file.

If you need to cite undefined entry keys during the draft phase, maybe you could just disable `defernumbers`.

If you insist on `defernumbers`, here is a way to write the label numbers to the `.aux` even if there is a Biber rerun request.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\blx@AtEndDocument{%
  \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}
    {\iftoggle{blx@runbiber}
      {\def\do#1{\blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{#1}}
       \dolistloop\blx@localnumaux}
      {}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A-01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  location = {Location},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume = {1},
}
@article{C04,
  author = {Cuthor 2, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume = {2},
}
@article{B03,
  author = {Buthor 2, C.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Charlie},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{authorA-01}% \cite{B02} \cite{C03}
\section{Biblio}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Undefined citation, but references are still numbered as expected.]